# Volatile vs Atomic type performance in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, volatile, atomic

In Java, I known that Atomic type satisfies 2 points:

- Atomicity
- Visibility

While volatile only satisfies the Visibility.

But how is the performance comparing between them?

(If Atomic type is better performed or equivalent to volatile, I think there's no use cases we should you volatile instead of Atomic type. Right?)

Comment: Have a look at the implementation of (say) AtomicInteger. Do you think that it's likely to be faster than a volatile field?

Comment: For the operations that you can perform in a thread-safe fashion with `volatile`, `volatile` will be faster.

Comment: *"I want more clear explanation about performace comparing between volatile and atomic, which is not mentioned in most of topics I have read."* - I have added another duplink that answers that more specifically.

Comment: And the answer to your parenthetical question at the end is: No ... because the premise of that question is incorrect.

Comment: Got it. Thank you all guys.

Comment: A volatile is atomic in the sense that a read is atomic and a write is atomic. Also thinking in terms of atomicity and visibility is too limited, you need to add ordering to this set.